# How to use localStorage Carefully in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, local-storage, angular-local-storage

Since localStorage data can be changed easily, how can we make access controls and more things secure in the Angular App.

Suppose our localstorage contains:

> data - {name:user, account_status:inactive,...}

The user can easily change the account_status from inactive to active and get all access. 
I am not just concerned about access control but also the other localstorage data which is used in angular.

Can I encrypt the data from the node server and store it in localstorage and decrypt it back when i want to use with the same secret key. Will this have some adverse effects.

Please suggest some methods which can be used.

Comment: Rule #1 of web development: **Never trust data that comes from the client**

Comment: @Daniel How should I make sure that the localstorage is not modified?

Comment: I am getting user data from the node server through REST APIs which use jwt and on the angular side I use localstorage to save the user data, then perform navigation and other operations using the localstorage values. Suggest some method which is safe to use

Answer (score 2):

You can create a common service for localstorage operation which will perform the encryption when storing data in localstorage and decryption when getting data from localstorage. You should encrypt key and value both so it is not easy to change the value in localstorage. You can use CryptoJS for encryption.

Answer (score 2):

That's execalty what happened back in the time with Spotify. The result ? With a little script, you could have spotify premium for free.

My point is, that you should not store sensitive data in the client side, and if you do so and use it, there should be a doucble checking (one from the client, one from the server) : if the user changes the values of the client, the server will check the validity of the requests anyway, and  refuse resources to the user.

To finish, my point is that you don't need to encrypt your data, or to stop using local storage : just be clever and double-check the user permissions.

Comment: I am getting user data from the node server through REST APIs which use jwt and on the angular side I use localstorage to save the user data, then perform navigation and other operations using the localstorage values. Can you please suggest some method... Can we use cookies, or encrypt localstorage data from the node server itself or some other way

Comment: Why would you store the data in the local storage, when already have a token ? The token contains all the user information you need !

Comment: token is for authentication... and the information in the token is visible to everyone but can't be changed. I need to decrypt the token in angular to use the info. and I need to store the token in localstorage.

Comment: Is it safe to verify and decrypt the token in the client side with the secret key used in node server.

Comment: Token is also for information carrying. Sure, the data is public, but the user knowing he has the admin role is different than the user being able to set himself the admin role. [Libraries exist](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) to ease your life with tokens. And no, you don't **need to**, you *want to*.

Comment: Laso, the token should carry non-sensitive information, such as the user information (that he's supposed to know already, because you know, it's him).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194230/discussion-between-therightdoctors-and-maryannah).

Answer (score 0):

The type data you are trying to store should never to stored on local-storage, especially for a serious production app. Data should always be hashed/encrypted on the server and then sent to the front end for further manipulation.

Comment: can you please suggest about the ways of encryption and what kind of data to be stored in localstorage, I am a bit confused since it could be easily changed by the user. Thanks

Comment: explain exactly what you want to do. from back to front end

Comment: I am getting user data from the node server through REST APIs which use jwt and on the angular side I use localstorage to save the user data, then perform navigation and other operations using the localstorage values.

Comment: in this case, theres no need to save it at all in local storage. No will be able to access it because its coming right from the database. The data is simply json from the database and it will be different everytime a new user log in. what you need to do is save a the data in a variable in the typescript file, then it can be loaded in the html template. if you later want to lets say update the user data from a form, then with the data that you received from the server, you can do two way data binding and then resubmit the updated data to the rest api.